# R paste() not working - encountering unexpected symbol?

Tags: r

new to R. Trying to build the "in(...)" clause of a SQL query using values in an R vector. Having problems building the final quoted string using the paste() function.

To illustrate:

```
> mylist <- c("1001", "2002", "3003") #imagine these are values in target table
> sQuote(mylist)
[1] "‘1001’" "‘2002’" "‘3003’"
> toString(sQuote(mylist))
[1] "‘1001’, ‘2002’, ‘3003’"
> paste( toString(sQuote(mylist)), sep="" collapse="" )
Error: unexpected symbol in "paste( toString(sQuote(mylist)), sep="" collapse"
>
```

Why is this error occurring? I am trying to build the string `"'1001', '2002', '3003'"`

Comment: sep, and collapse are parameters in the function paste(). you need to put commas between each parameter when you call the function

Comment: yes - thank you. I was hunting down a bigger problem to do with paste and paste0 outputs being written to the file very literally... including the "c('...','...')". So i created the little test above to try and understand paste() a bit better. I still had the larger problem on my mind and wasn't paying attention to syntax; my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this counts as an answer - you missed a comma:

`paste(toString(sQuote(mylist)), collapse = "")`